# How do you compile a Fortran program which links to Dislin libraries, but also to other modules?

Tags: module, fortran, gfortran

When a program written in Fortran links to Dislin, I use:

```
gfortran -c program.f90

dlink program
```

Say that the program must also be linked to another module, meaning the first command is:

```
gfortran -c Module1.f90 program.f90
```

What does the dlink command look like in this case? Looking through the Dislin manual I can't seem to find an answer, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Compiler says it cannot find -ldislin despite everything being in the dislin folder, the libraries being installed correctly, and dlink having successfully linked in the past. Any ideas?

Comment: @VladimirF Those first two commands in the original post work perfectly for programs without any attached modules. The problem is that dlink only takes as an argument the name of the main program. When attempting to link, there are then undefined references to the module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, here is the solution if anyone needs it:

```
dlink progname
```

is equivalent to:

```
gfortran -o progname.exe progname.o   C:\dislin\disgf.a -luser32 -lgdi32 -lopengl32
```

Therefore the command to use to compile is:

```
gfortran Module1.f95 progname.f95  C:\dislin\disgf.a -luser32 -lgdi32 -lopengl32
```

Comment: Ok, you use Windows, perhaps worth mentioning, or using the [tag:windows] tag.